# uploaded files but showing "[ ]" instead of uploaded files

Tags: python, django

I am new to django filehandling. The process is going well with no errors but no files are stored after uploading.
Instead, the value `[]` is stored in document column insted of the uploaded document.
I uploaded only one document.

**view:-**

```
class Build_Kb(FormView):
    template_name = "template.html"
    form_class = Build_form
    success_url = '/thanks/'
      def form_valid(self, form):
        title=form.cleaned_data.get("title")
        knowledge=form.cleaned_data.get("knowledge")
        document=self.request.FILES.getlist('document')
        share_with=form.cleaned_data.get("share_with")
        instance = Buildkb.objects.create(title=title,knowledge=knowledge,document=document)
        for user in share_with:
            instance.share_with.add(user)
            instance.save()
        messages.success(self.request, "Knowledge saved succesfully")
        return redirect("/")
```

**model**

```
class Buildkb(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    knowledge=models.TextField(blank=False)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    share_with=models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: But your `document` is a *list*.

Comment: Did you set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in `settings.py`?

Comment: any documentation with formview for file upload or plz give some example

Comment: yes ,MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are done

Comment: You probably forgot to set the HTML form's tag "enctype" attribute to "multipart/form-data". Also, you should be using a ModelForm instead of manually building the instance from the form's data.

Comment: I used modelform ,not manually